# Understanding a Result About Cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

I am trying to understand the above proof, particularly the line "For then by corollary 4.3. we must have $[G : K] = |I \times J|$, whence..." How do we know that the the number of ***all*** cosets of $K$ in $G$ is $|I \times J|$; how do we know that every coset arises as $Kb_j a_i$, where $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ are, I believe, minimal set of right coset representatives?

Here is an attachment containing corollary 4.3:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Claim: Let $G$ be some group, $H$ some subgroup, and $M$ a nonempty subset of $G$. If $G = \sqcup_{g \in M} Hg$, then $M$ is a minimal set of right coset representatives (MSRCR).

Proof: Suppose the contrary, that $S \subseteq M$ is a MSRCR. Then there exists a $g' \in M \setminus S$. However, it is clearly the case that $G \setminus \sqcup_{g \in S} Hg = Hg'$, since all of the elements in $Hg'$ are not contained in any of the $Hg$ where $g \in S$. Hence, $M$ is the MSRCR. A corollary of this is that $|M| = [G : H]$.

Does this seem right; is this the idea needed to make the final conclusion?

Comment: That is a silly writer to blame. They are trying to say, it's clear to show that $Ka_ib_j$ are distinct. Because if they are, then we have that by *Cor 4.3*... And then they go on to show it. Bad writing plays with your mind.

Comment: Out of interest, what book is this?

Comment: @mdave16 This comes from Hungerford. I am not exactly sure I follow what you are saying. Are you saying there a flaw in the proof, or that Hungerford hasn't presented his ideas clearly?

Comment: the latter. So when he says "It suffices to show X. For then by Cor 4.3, we must have Y", he means to say "It suffices to show X. Because if X, then by Cor 4.3, we have Y. Now to prove X." Where X, Y are the obvious statements.

Comment: It may be helpful to think of it like this: cosets of $H$ chop $G$ up into $H$-sized bits. Cosets of $K$ chop $H$ into $K$-sized bits. So, for each $K$-sized bit in $H$, we get a similar $K$-sized bit in the coset $gH$; in other words, the $K$ cosets represent a *refinement* of the partition of $G$ by $H$ (each $K$ coset is entirely contained in an $H$ coset).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"How do we know that every coset arises as $Kb_ja_i$ [...] ?"
This follows from the equality 
$$G = \bigcup_{(i,j)\in I\times J} Kb_ja_i$$
shown before. Thus every element from $G$ is in some coset $Kb_ja_i$, and so every coset of $K$ has the form $Kb_ja_i$.

(I think of the disjointness as follows: The disjoint decomposition $H=\bigcup_j Kb_j$ is mapped onto a disjoint decomposition $ Ha_i = \bigcup_j Kb_ja_i$ by multiplying everything with $a_i$ from the right. The disjointness is preserved because multiplying with a group element is an injective (in fact, bijective) map.)

**Edit** (addressing comments and edit of OP):  Let $H$ be an arbitrary subgroup of $G$. By the corollary, two right cosets of $H$ are either equal, or they have no element in common. Thus the cosets partition $G$. By the definition that I know, a Minimal Set of Right Coset Representatives $M$ is defined by picking exactly one element from each coset. In other words, $M$ is a "MSRCR" if and only if $M$ contains exactly one element from each coset: $|M\cap Hg| = 1 $ for all $g\in G$. So I would say that $|M|= |G:H|$ by definition. And I would also say that this definition tells us that $M$ is a "MSRCR" if and only if $G =\bigsqcup_{m\in M} Hm$.
In your edit, you can only conclude that $Hg' \subseteq G\setminus \bigsqcup_{g\in S}Hg$, but otherwise the argument is correct. (I only think it is somewhat more complicated than needed.)

Comment: So, are you saying that, because $Kb_j a_i$ are right cosets of $K$ in $G$ for $(i,j) \in I \times J$, and the very fact that their union is $G$ implies $\{b_j a_i ~|~ (i,j) \in I \times J \}$ forms the minimal set of right coset representatives? I think this point needs justification; it seems obvious but I am unsure how to prove it. Perhaps a proof by contradiction, and perhaps we contradict the fact that $\{b_j ~|~ j \in J \}$ and $\{a_i ~|~ i \in I \}$ are minimal set of right coset representatives.

Comment: Okay. Perhaps I have a proof; let me edit my OP.